# Better way to center text next to image on two sides (left and bottom) css only

Tags: css, image, text, center, dimensions

It's very easy to center text next to an image on just one side or opposing sides (left/right or top/bottom), but I need to center some text text along the left of an image and some more text along the bottom side.

I have gone through several solutions but each of them require manually centering one piece of text or the other. In my solution below I chose to manual apply vertical centering on the left side because horizontally centering text on the bottom would require padding to change with length of text.

Javascript would be pretty easy. something along the lines of

```
element.style.paddingTop = (Img_Height/2 - Txt_Height/2);
```

But I find it hard to believe there isn't a pure CSS solution.

Is there a better way to accomplish the same effect of this code below?
See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gamil/yteBY/

```
<div class="Preview">
    <p class="Preview" style="padding-top: 54px;">120 pixels high</p>
    <ul class="Preview">
        <li><img alt="big preview" src="http://placehold.it/160x120" /></li>
        <li>160 pixels wide</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="Preview" style="padding-top: 30px;margin-left: 30px;">
    <p class="Preview" style="padding-top: 23px;">60 pixels high</p>
    <ul class="Preview">
        <li><img alt="big preview" src="http://placehold.it/80x60" /></li>
        <li>80 pixels wide</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Preview {
    float: left;
}
ul.Preview > li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate?

Comment: if you follow the jfiddle link you'll see that I have acheived it by hard-coding the padding-top for the left-side text, and using "text-align: center;" on the bottom. I would like to do this in such a way that I don't have to manually figure the correct pixels on each div and paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Horiztonal alignement is indeed easy, it's a little trickier for vertical alignment. [Here is a good article on vertical alignment](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

So concerning your problem, here is a first solution : [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/aviruj/2/edit)
This solution is not perfect as in the css I do:

```
.textC{
  position:absolute; 
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

Which means that the text *begins* at 50% from left and top. Which is not what you exactly want (from what I have understood).

With a little javascript, you can get the size of your text and replace it exactly at the center of the picture. [See the JSBIN solution with javascript](http://jsbin.com/utavuy/1/edit)

EDIT: Here is a new solution, only using CSS : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Pwbf/2/)

I explain just a snippet of the css code

```
.block1{
  #position: absolute;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.block2{
  #position: relative;
  display: block;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Basically adding `#` to the position selects the center of the object instead of the top left corner.

Thank you to [this website](http://benalman.com/code/test/css-centering.html) which really hinted me the right solution to your problem!

Comment: If you follow the JSFiddle link i provided in the OP, you'll see that I am attempting to center text outside on the edges, not inside. I alredy have a solution, but I don't like it because it's not flexible and requires manually setting padding on one of the texts. I chose to center the side text since the padding wouldn't vary with the length of the text.

Comment: Oh, sorry could not get to the fiddle during the day (it was kind of down...). But basically you can take the approach of my javascript solution and use it _oustide_ instead of inside. Once you have the value of the length of your text, you do any math you want, without having to "setting manually".

Comment: Yeah, Javascript would be pretty easy. Image_Height/2 - text_height/2. But I find it hard to believe there isn't a pure CSS solution.

Comment: You're absolutely right! So I made some research (since it is indeed hard to believe) and finally found a css-only solution. You may find it in my edited answer.